# How might javascript to update dropdown options conflict with CakePHP's save?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, select

This code causes my save to either flash "404 not found" when in a modal dialog or goes to a blank white page when in a separate tab.

Heres the code:

```
<script>
function changeSelection()
{
var value = $('#typeSelect').val();
var div = document.getElementById('sigType');

    if(value >= 1 && value <= 3)
    { 
        var signalTypeOptions = 
             <?php echo json_encode( array_values( $signalTypeOptions));?>;
        var selection = document.getElementById('valueSelect');
        selection.innerHTML = '';

        var i = 0;
        for(optionText in signalTypeOptions[value])
        {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = optionText;
            selection.appendChild(option);
        }
        $(div).show(); 
    }
    else
    {
        $(div).hide(); 
    }
}
</script>
```

The code is used to update the dropdown options for a secondary select element (valueSelect) based off of an initial select element (typeSelect).

I found that when a value is selected in the dynamically populated dropdown, the html doesn't reflect the selection.

Comment: This could be because of the SecurityComponent not allowing you to modify the form. Do you have that enabled? Also, make sure you have debug set to 2 in Config/core.php, it will show you a more descriptive error.

Comment: +1 for kaisoks comment, also; is the javascript creating the *right* options in your dropdown? You don't seem to assign a 'value' to the options in your dropdown and by using `array_values( $signalTypeOptions)`, you're 'stripping' the original index (which may be the *id/value* if those values come from a `Model::find('list')` in CakePHP.

Comment: Thats a good question. I also tried setting the value, hence the random variable 'i' that incremented for every loop. The value in the box doesn't seem to be the problem because, for testing, i changed the values passed in the beforeSave. Also, i made sure all my callbacks return their parents function so they wont return false. i had the debug set to 2 but i changed it to 3 because some places said to do that.

Comment: I think the problem might be in what is "selected". When inspecting the source, it never shows up with whats selected in the code.

Comment: My guess the problem is the json var created... Could you do a `console.log(signalTypeOptions)` and paste the output in your question? Also, something kind of off-topic, why are you using pure javascript mixed with jQuery code? Isn't it easier to make it all jquery or all js?

Comment: Its a massive multidimensional array that doesnt get fully displayed, still want me to post it? I tried many different variations of the array and it prints out fine. All appear green in the console logs.